# Select 1 item per attribute value in Spring Data MongoRepository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-mongodb

I have a collection of objects in MongoDB and am using Spring Data MongoDB.

My collection of entities look something like this:

```
--------------------------------------------
| id        | snapshot      | name         |
--------------------------------------------
| 2         | somedate      | bla          |
| 2         | somedate      | foo          |
| 3         | somedate      | bar          |
| 3         | somedate      | cheese       |
| 6         | somedate      | milk         |
| 6         | somedate      | lorum        |
| 6         | somedate      | ipsum        |
| 9         | somedate      | do           |
| 10        | somedate      | re           |
| 10        | somedate      | mi           |
| 15        | somedate      | fa           |    
--------------------------------------------
```

I want to get a list of objects where I want to have only one object of each distinct id, the object for that id should be the one with the latest date.

My result should be something like this:

```
--------------------------------------------
| id        | snapshot      | name         |
--------------------------------------------
| 2         | somedate      | bla          |
| 3         | somedate      | bar          |
| 6         | somedate      | milk         |
| 9         | somedate      | do           |
| 10        | somedate      | mi           |
| 15        | somedate      | fa           |    
--------------------------------------------
```

Is this possible in using a `MongoRepository` query?
I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the aggregation framework it's possible. Run the following aggregation operation to get the desired result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "snapshot": -1 } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$id",
            "snapshot": { "$first": "$snapshot" },
            "name": { "$first": "$name" }
        }
    }
])
```

The above native aggregation operation can then be translated to Spring Data MongoDB aggregation as:

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;

TypedAggregation<Entity> aggregation = newAggregation(Entity.class,
    sort(DESC, "snapshot"),
    group("id")
        .first("snapshot").as("snapshot")
        .first("name").as("name")
);

AggregationResults<EntityStats> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, EntityStats.class);
```